# Routing between modules in a Play application

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've just read document [Working with sub-projects](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects) and tried to create a test application with two modules... and to be honest there are a few things I'm not clear on.

For instance, I've created a test application that consists of a main module and an authorization module. If the user is not logged in, the application should redirect to the authorization module... and when done redirect back to the main module. Furthermore, the main module always depends on the authorization module to determine whether or not the user is allowed to access a given functionality or resource.

That said, my questions are:

1. Is is correct to have the modules of an application referencing each other (e.g.  the main module referencing the authorization module and the authorization module referencing the main module)?
2. How do I share resources between modules (mainly HTML templates)?
3. What's about the assets? Should they be shared or each module should have their own assets?

The idea would be to have an application made of a set of modules - each showing the same menu, and let them jump from one to another. Unfortunately it looks like there are not much examples around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many questions here, one answer.

You must have a root application, and modules. The modules are referenced as dependencies, so from the main app, you can use modules' ressources (and assets) just like if they was in the root app (if two ressources are in both, the root's one is taken). But the opposite is not true, modules shoudn't know about the root app.

If you do want to share ressources between all your modules (and maybe your app), you should create a common module that is referenced as dependency in all modules.